# Copy a discord user's avatar and nickname to bot

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a joke bot that basically "steals" his nickname and avatar but I've had no success

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=.01)
async def avatar(*, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = client.get_user(id=<id>)
    userAvatar = discord.Member.avatar_url
    bot.user.edit(avatar=userAvatar)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the code that I have done, You have to create 2 folders Avatars/Steal_av
and then what this code does is that it gets the user's avatar and stores it in Stolen.png then sets it as his avatar/PFP, but you have to get his password and put it in a config file, **without the password it doesn't work**.
If you still need me to tell you how to do the steal nickname tell me but I thought you won't want it since I told you that it doesn't work unless you have his password.

```
#Imports
import requests
from PIL import Image

with open('Avatars/Steal_av/Stolen.png', 'wb') as f:
   r = requests.get(user.avatar_url, stream=True)
   for block in r.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break
        f.write(block)
Image.open('Avatars/Steal_av/Stolen.png').convert('RGB')
with open('Avatars/Steal_av/Stolen.png', 'rb') as f:
   await client.user.edit(password=password, avatar=f.read())
```